# UIImage in landscape programmatically

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have an image (small button) which looks perfect in Portrait Orientation, but my whole App is running in Landscape Right mode, however the image does not change to landscape.

I want to do it programmatically

I tried:

```
NSString *pathToImg = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DetonatorSmall" ofType:@"png"];

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pathToImg];
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];

imgView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3.14159265/2);

[button setImage:imgView.image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

But the image is still in portrait.

Any ideas what I can do?

Comment: Are you changing the transform anywhere else? Also, please use `M_PI_2` for the angle. It's more clear and you won't get problems with integer division.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pathToImg];
[button setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI / 2.0)];//Left
[button setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( M_PI / 2.0)];//Right
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself! :)

I added the image to a button, before it was drawn, so the button was the one I had to move. I applied the .transform to the imageview, but I had to do it fro the button :)

Can be closed